# как создать файл, который сам распределит файлы, по нужным папкам

Tags: windows, консоль, swing, cmd

поскольку я сам не являюсь программистом, мой вопрос возможно покажется странным для вас. все что мне нужно понять, это как в консоли написать код, который при запуске файла будет раскидывать нужные директории в заданные папки. (это нужно мне для более удобной установки пресетов для плагинов). я видел подобный файл в "plugin alliance" и мне показалось это очень удобным, но там это нужно для установки плагинов, а мне для установки пресетов. код там выглядит примерно так:

````
".\installer\Setup ADA Flanger v1.4.1.exe" /SILENT /COMPONENTS="VST3_64"
".\installer\Setup ADA STD-1 Stereo Tapped Delay v1.4.1.exe" /SILENT /COMPONENTS="VST3_64" ```

*мне нужно сделать подобный код, но чтобы он переносил папки в документы*

например папку "Franchise Infiltrator preset bank" из архива мне нужно перенести по расположению:
 C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\DeviousMachines\Infiltrator\Library\Presets\main
````

Comment: Вопрос не слишком понятен.  И почему стоит тег `swing`?  Это должно быть Java-приложение с графическим интерфейсом?

Comment: Смотрите документацию по `bat` файлам. Делайте отбор в исходной директории и перемещайте по условию в нужное местоположение